# How to display the text in one line in wpf textblock

Tags: wpf, textblock

I'm a newbie with wpf , what i want to display the text in one line in wpf textblock. 
eg.:

```
<TextBlock 
    Text ="asfasfasfa
    asdasdasd"
</TextBlock>
```

TextBlock display it in two lines default,

but i want it in only one line like this"asafsf asfafaf". I mean show all the text in one line even there are more than one lines in the text
   what should i do?

Answer (score 17):

Use a Converter:

```
    <TextBlock Text={Binding Path=TextPropertyName,
Converter={StaticResource SingleLineTextConverter}}
```

SingleLineTextConverter.cs:

```
public class SingleLineTextConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = (string)value;
        s = s.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");
        return s;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How about if you gave the converter source code as an example here? I don't have VS handy so I can't paste it in. The source code would make this the definitive answer.

Comment: Liked the idea, thanks. But I had to a null-check in the beginning of the Convert() method, otherwise I got a null reference exception.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of this:

```
            <TextBlock Text="Hello
                How Are
                You??"/>
```

Use this:

```
            <TextBlock>
                Hello
                How Are
                You??
            </TextBlock>
```

or this:

```
            <TextBlock>
                <Run>Hello</Run> 
                <Run>How Are</Run> 
                <Run>You??</Run>
            </TextBlock>
```

or set Text property in code behind like this :

`(In XAML)`

```
            <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock"/>
```

`(In code - c#)`

```
            MyTextBlock.Text = "Hello How Are You??"
```

Code-behind approach has an advantage that you can format your text before setting it.
Example: If the text is retrieved from a file and you want to remove any carriage-return new-line characters you can do it this way:

```
 string textFromFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Path\To\Text\File.txt");
 MyTextBlock.Text = textFromFile.Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","");
```

Comment: Actually the text to display is in a file, so i can't do it like that , is there another way?  Thank you very much.