# How to disable return in a property bound to a GridViewColumn?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a GridView which is bound to a list of objects. One of the properties is `Notes`. But it appears really tall in the GridView making the row take one or more row spaces which is insane because the `Notes` column accepts returns.

Is there a way to disable return only for the display of that property?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a converter on the multiline field that replaces `\r\n` and `\n`.

Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115520/how-to-display-the-text-in-one-line-in-wpf-textblock)